# SDL2 segfaults on key press

Tags: c, graphics, 3d, keyboard, segmentation-fault

My program segfaults as soon as I press a key, but I am unable to come up with a minimal code. If I comment out `pixels[y][pdpix] = col[sampleX][sampleY];` (line 110), key presses work as normal. Otherwise, it segfaults.

Full code and "bmp" files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1663hiKbvodcNu0xG8FpbYACAUoGScfAn/view?usp=sharing

Code in main.c:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "read.h"
#define RESX 960
#define RESY 540
#define HRESX 480
#define DRAWDISTANCE 360
#define ROTSPEED 0.005
#define BGCOL 0
#define ARESY 539




void main() {
  readCW();
  bool running = true;

  SDL_Window* window =  NULL;
  SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

  if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )  {
    printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    running = false;
  }
  window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, RESX, RESY, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
  if( window==NULL) {
    printf( "SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    running = false;
  }
  renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
  if(renderer==NULL) {
    printf("Renderer error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    running = false;
  }

  SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
       SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, RESX,RESY);

  readBW();


  float playerX = 512;
  float playerY = 512;
  float dirX = 0.0;
  float dirY = 1.0;

  void rotatez(float rotspeed) {
    float oldDirX = dirX;
    dirX = dirX * cos(rotspeed) - dirY * sin(rotspeed);
    dirY = oldDirX * sin(rotspeed) + dirY * cos(rotspeed);
  }

  const Uint8* keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState( NULL );
  while( running ) {

    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = SDL_GetTicks();

    Uint32 pixels[RESY][RESX] = {[0 ... RESY-1][0 ...RESX-1] = 0x5555FF};

    SDL_Event e;
    running  = !(SDL_PollEvent( &e ) && e.type == SDL_QUIT);

    if(keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE]) running = false;
    if(keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) rotatez(-ROTSPEED);
    if(keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) rotatez(ROTSPEED);
    if(keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_W]) {
      playerY += dirY;
      playerX += dirX;
    }
    if(keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_S]) {
      playerY -= dirY;
      playerX -= dirX;
    }
    if(keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_A]) {
      playerY -= dirX;
      playerX += dirY;
    }
    if(keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_D]) {
      playerY += dirX;
      playerX -= dirY;
    }
    //rotatez(-ROTSPEED);

      playerY -= dirY;//for testing
      playerX -= dirX;//for testing
    int heightBuffer[RESX] = {[0 ... 959] = RESY};
    int playerHeight = 80;//disp[(int)playerX][(int)playerY] + 50;
    int dpix = 0;

    for( int dDist = 1; dDist < DRAWDISTANCE; dDist+=1) {

      for( int pix = -dDist; pix < dDist; pix++) {

        int pdpix = dpix;
        dpix = (pix/(float)dDist+1) *HRESX;

        int sampleX = (int)playerX + dDist*dirX + pix*-dirY;
        int sampleY = (int)playerY + dDist*dirY + pix*dirX;

        int height = disp[sampleX][sampleY];

        int heightOnScreen = ( ((float)playerHeight - height) / dDist * 240 + 240);    //alg for persp proj
        if(heightOnScreen > 0 && heightOnScreen < RESY) {
          for( pdpix; pdpix < dpix; pdpix++) {
            if(heightOnScreen < heightBuffer[pdpix]) {
              for(int y = heightBuffer[pdpix]; y > heightOnScreen; y-=1) {
                pixels[y][pdpix] = col[sampleX][sampleY]; //if I comment out this line, segfault goes away.
              }
              heightBuffer[pdpix] = heightOnScreen;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, pixels, RESX * sizeof(Uint32));
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );
    t2 = SDL_GetTicks();
    printf("%ld fps\n", 1000/(t2-t1));
  }
  SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
  SDL_DestroyRenderer( renderer );
  SDL_DestroyTexture( texture );
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: It seems like it segfaults when trying to access one of your arrays (`pixels` or `col`). Check exact values of `y`, `pdpix`, `sampleX`, `sampleY`. They shouldn't be ever out of range of your array bounds.

Comment: regarding: `void main() {`  There are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice that they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`